# Gzip Javascript not decompressing in browser

Tags: javascript, gzip

**Sorry, this was a non-problem, Chrome cache was giving me the old version of the file in Incognito mode.**

Tangent: As website owners, cache is very important to save cash on hosting. But when I'm the user, I never want to use cache on **any** website. AFAIK there's no way to completely and permanently disable cache 24/7 in Chrome, which is a massive deal-breaker if Chrome weren't free.

Original question below:

---

What I've done:

- Copy-pasted my Javascript into Closure Compiler
- Copied the minified Javascript into a new file named `spa_asdf.js`
- Use 7-zip to compress to `spa.js.gz` with maximum compression setting
- Renamed that gzipped file to `spa.js`
- Uploaded `spa.js` to S3 bucket
- Set the S3 metadata `Content-Type: application/javascript` and `Content-Encoding: gzip`
- Set permissions to be publicly accessible

If I view `spa.js` in my browser, it decompresses properly and shows me the uncompressed code. If it's loaded by `<script>` in a page, it doesn't work, and both Chrome and IE11 show a bunch of unrecognizable characters in the file.

How do I get the file to decompress when used inside of `<script>`?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Or are you just using the `file://` protocol?

Comment: My website is on nginx, the file is on S3

Comment: When you say "Set the metadata Content-Type: application/javascript and Content-Encoding: gzip", do you mean in the html markup? In the web server configuration?

Comment: @Asaph No, I mean in S3 metadata, which may be the analog of web server configuration

Comment: Please share the public S3 url so I can test.

Comment: @Asaph //mcmaster-static.s3.amazonaws.com/spa.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> If it's loaded by  in a page, it doesn't work

but here's basic snippet loading this script and everything works just fine in Chrome (I've added `jquery` to avoid script error, because your script depends on presence of `$`):

```js
document.querySelector('.whatever').textContent = typeof $jscomp;
```

```css
.whatever {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mcmaster-static.s3.amazonaws.com/spa.js"></script>
<div class="whatever"></div>
```

Comment: Did you look at `spa.js` in DevTools?

Comment: ah it is now, must've been the cache... /facepalm Probably should delete this question...